# Fetch data from source sheet based on emails provided in the Emails tab in the target spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a problem where I have two sheets. one sheet is the [source spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19FkL3rsh5sxdujb6x00BUPvXEEhiXfAeURTeQi3YWzo/) and another is a target spreadsheet. The source spreadsheet has a source sheet has which is the master database and the [target spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AThfeK1gWEbV7qiM4CLTszd-T170tn4kTfybW6fcZN0/) has the target where we want to fetch data from source sheet based on emails provided in the Emails tab in the target spreadsheet.

I want the following things to happen with a script and not with IMPORTRANGE or QUERY:

The target spreadsheet will have multiple copies so I want to connect the target spreadsheet with the source spreadsheet based on the source spreadsheet's id.

I want the email matches to be case insensitive so that the users of the target spreadsheet can type emails in any case.

The Emails can go up to 50 or let's say get the last row for that column.

It will be great if the script shows a pop up saying updated after it has fetched the data.

The source sheet might have data up to 15000 rows so I am thinking about speed too.

I have shared both of the spreadsheets with hyperlinks to their names. I am not really great at scripts so it will be helpful if you can leave comments in it wherever you feel like. I would truly appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance!

Script here:

```
function fetch() {
  //get the sheets
  var source_Ssheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('19FkL3rsh5sxdujb6x00BUPvXEEhiXfAeURTeQi3YWzo');
  var target_Ssheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  //get the tabs
  var email_sheet = target_Ssheet.getSheetByName("Emails");
  var target_sheet = target_Ssheet.getSheetByName("Target Sheet");
  var source_sheet = source_Ssheet.getSheetByName("Source Sheet");

  //get ranges
  var email_list = email_sheet.getRange("B2:B");
  var target_sheet_range = target_sheet.getRange("A1:F100");
  var source_sheet_range = source_sheet.getRange("A1:F100");

  //get last rows
  var last_email_name = email_list.getLastRow();
  var last_target_sheet_range = target_sheet_range.getLastRow();
  var last_source_sheet_range = source_sheet_range.getLastRow();

  //start searching for emails
  for (var i=3; i < last_email_name.length+1; i++)
  {
    for(varj=3; j< last_source_sheet_range.length+1; j++ )
    {
        if(source_sheet_range[j][3].getValue() == email_list[i][3].getValue())
        {
          //copy matches to target sheet
          target_sheet.getRange((last_target_sheet_range + 1),1,1,10).setValues(master_sheet_range[j].getValues()); 
        }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I will not follow links to spreadsheets.  Put all the information that you need into your question and I would suggest focusing on one specific question at a time.

Comment: Makes sense @Cooper ... My major problem with this script is that this nested for loop doesn’t return any value. Can you look into that?

Comment: If your problem is with the loop, you should **consider editing this question to that specific problem only** i.e ( you are not getting return value ). As of now it's so broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things

1. `last_email_name` and `last_source_sheet_range` are numbers - they do not have any length, this is why your first `for`loops are not working
2. You are missing a space in `varj=3;`
3. `email_list[i][3].getValue()` does not exist because `email_list` only includes `B`  - that only one column. I assume you meant `email_list[i][0].getValue()`
4. ranges cannot be addressed with the indices `[][]`, you need to retrieve the values first to have a 2D value range.
5. You email values in the different sheets do not follow the same case. Apps Script is case sensitive, to suee the `==` comparison you need to use the `toLowerCase()` method.
6. Also mind that defining `getRange("B2:B")` will include many empty rows that you don't need and will make your code very slow. Replace it through `getRange("B2:B" + email_sheet.getLastRow());`

Have a look here at the debugged code - keep in mind that there is still much room for improvement.

```
function fetch() {
  //get the sheets
  var source_Ssheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('19FkL3rsh5sxdujb6x00BUPvXEEhiXfAeURTeQi3YWzo');
  var target_Ssheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  //get the tabs
  var email_sheet = target_Ssheet.getSheetByName("Emails");
  var target_sheet = target_Ssheet.getSheetByName("Target Sheet");
  var source_sheet = source_Ssheet.getSheetByName("Source Sheet");

  //get ranges
  var email_list = email_sheet.getRange("B2:B" + email_sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var target_sheet_range = target_sheet.getRange("A1:F100").getValues();
  var source_sheet_range = source_sheet.getRange("A1:F100").getValues();
  var last_target_sheet_range = target_sheet.getLastRow();
  //start searching for emails
  for (var i=1; i < email_list.length; i++)
  {
    for(var j=1; j< source_sheet_range.length; j++ )
    {
        if(source_sheet_range[j][0].toLowerCase() == email_list[i][0].toLowerCase())
        {
          target_sheet.getRange((last_target_sheet_range + 1),1,1,6).setValues([source_sheet_range[j]]); 
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your changes! I could use this script but it only takes the last value of the email list and return just one entry from the range. Do you know how we can debug that? I am new to google scripts and can't figure that out after a few attempts.

Comment: The script as it is will always overwrite the last row when defining `target_sheet.getRange((last_target_sheet_range + 1),1,1,6)`. Instead you need to retrieve always dynamically the last row, so `target_sheet.getRange((target_sheet.getLastRow() + 1),1,1,6)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, @ziganotschka ... this worked like charm. I just have one problem with it though, it takes all the listed entries from the sheet every time. I am thinking about making another column of timestamp and the script will scan only the range of data which has timestamp grater than what we have when we ran the script the last time. This way the script will be more efficient I think. Can you give me a rough guidance on how I can do that?